# How update password by firebase in kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I have app using firebase by kotlin
I want change/update password in Account
I use this code but don't success change password

```
val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

            user!!.updatePassword(editTextPassword.text.toString().trim()).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    println("Update Success")
                } else {
                    println("Erorr Update")
                }
            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change password with Firebase for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39866086/change-password-with-firebase-for-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#set_a_users_password
>
> **Important**: To set a user's password, the **user must have signed in
>   recently.**

Also, try using this:

```
val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
val txtNewPass = editTextPassword.text

user!!.updatePassword(txtNewPass).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        println("Update Success")
    } else {
        println("Error Update")
    }
}
```