# Android studio firbase change password validate form error

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, logic

Hello i simply want to match 2 fields if they match i want to send 1 of them to firebase. this is for changing password. however im getting error and it goes right away to the else statement: "Something went wrong, password did not get changed". cant understand why.

right now if 2 password does not match im getting the message: both fields much match 
this part is right

when 2 matches i get something went wrong : thats the else statement for public void oncomplete for firebase. it simply skip if the task is sucsessful and i dont understand why.

```
public void changePassword(){
   String userPasswordNew = newPassword.getText().toString(); // get pw
    String userPassword2New = newPassword2.getText().toString();

    if (userPasswordNew.equals(userPassword2New)){

        if(userPasswordNew.equals("") || userPassword2New.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(ProfilePasswordUpdateActivity.this,"Fields can not be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else {
            firebaseUser.updatePassword(userPasswordNew).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(ProfilePasswordUpdateActivity.this,"Password changed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(ProfilePasswordUpdateActivity.this,"Something went wrong, password did not get changed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(ProfilePasswordUpdateActivity.this,"Both fields much match in order to change password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

the xml binding for the inputs

```
 newPassword = findViewById(R.id.EditText_new_password);
 newPassword2 = findViewById(R.id.EditText_new_password2);
```

error

2020-01-15 08:57:44.007 11071-11071/com.example.examapplikation E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.examapplikation, PID: 11071
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.reauthenticate(com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.examapplikation.ProfilePasswordUpdateActivity.changePassword(ProfilePasswordUpdateActivity.java:66)
        at com.example.examapplikation.ProfilePasswordUpdateActivity$1.onClick(ProfilePasswordUpdateActivity.java:50)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Comment: My guess is that it's throwing a FirebaseAuthRecentLoginRequiredException, could you add the stacktrace you're getting or confirm that that's the problem? If that's the case I'll explain an easy fix.

Comment: how can i add this ? stacktrace

Comment: actually it worked before i added the second if statement where i also check if fields are empty and not only if the 2 inputs were equal.  but then it crash if something was empty but changed password sucsesfully when both fields were equal. however now it goes directly to the else statement in the changepassword function to firebase.

Comment: Sorry that's not enough of it, try editing the question and adding it fully, or just search if FirebaseAuthRecentLoginRequiredException appears in it. From what you're saying it sounds like that would be the problem but I prefer to be sure before writing an answer so check that please

Comment: but how does the if statement i created look. its correct or maybe some logical error i made in it?

Comment: That's correct, if it wasn't the code inside the else wouldn't execute. Anyway if you want to be sure try deleting it and running the code again, you will see that that's not the problem

Comment: In the else part instead of showing a toast do `throw task.getException()` and you'll see the cause of the call failing.

Comment: Please read [How-to-get-StackTrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841232/java-android-how-to-print-out-a-full-stack-trace).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you. as [nilsi's SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40904516/10182897) says you need to reauthenticate the user to change the Password. I made changes in your Logic might this will help you. Just reauthenticate user before change password.

```
String userPasswordNew = newPassword.getText().toString();
String userPassword2New = newPassword2.getText().toString();

if(!userPasswordNew.equals("") && !userPassword2New.equals("")){
    if(userPasswordNew.equals(userPassword2New)){
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider
                .getCredential("user@example.com", "password1234");
        user.reauthenticate(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            user.updatePassword(userPasswordNew).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "Password updated");
                                    } else {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "Error password not updated")
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error auth failed")
                        }
                    }
                });
    }else{
        Log.d("Password", "Does Not Match");
    }
}else{
    Log.d("Password", "Fill the Edittext");
}
```

Comment: hello my app just crashes with this. and btw im already signed in so i dont get why i have to reauthenticate?

Comment: it worked before i added the second if statement for also checking if fields are empty so app dont crash

Comment: Please read proper details why you need to reauthenticate and please explain on which if condition your app crash ?

Comment: Please post acitvity code properly and post crash log

Comment: the crash log is to long to write here i an edit my question with it

Comment: i now updated the oroginal post with the crash msg because it was to long to write it here

Comment: as your crash report say your reauth in null because you didn't reauth properly

Comment: i think everything was a bugg my original code works now . however your solution is probally more secure than mine

Comment: thank you for the help:) and by the way those logs. do they give any output on screen? and how can  i make log work the tag is red for me

Comment: It will provided inside log cat

Answer (score -1):

Some security-sensitive actions—such as deleting an account, setting a primary email address, and changing a password—require that the user has recently signed in. If you perform one of these actions, and the user signed in too long ago, the action fails with an error. When this happens, re-authenticate the user by getting new sign-in credentials from the user and passing the credentials to reauthenticateWithCredential.

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var credential;

// Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials

user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential).then(function() {
  // User re-authenticated.
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

Comment: Please provide in android format and please don't copy and paste the another answer instead just provide link of answer